# How do I create a dictionary from a file using Python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, key

Question: How do I open a file and turn it into my dictionary when I run the program?

So I created a test dictionary, saved it as .txt and .dat. Below I have entered the dictionary manually, but instead I want the program to open the file when ran, convert it to the dictionary, then continue into the functions.

(The overall objective of the program is to enter a key (productCode) to retrieve the product number, all of which works), but I want it to do it with the file, and not the manually entered data.

As always, guidance is appreciated!

```
file = open("test.dat", "r")

FILENAME = "test.dat"


# ------ Global Variables -------
d = {'ABCD': '0123', 'HJKL': '0987'}

user_cont = True

# ------- Functions -------

print("Product number finder.")
def get_productNum2():
    global d
    user_cont = True
    while user_cont:

        productCode = input("Enter an existing product code: ")
        if productCode in d:
            productNum = d[productCode]
            print("Product #: " + productNum)
        else:
            print("Error finding product number; product code does not exist.")

        user_cont = user_continue()

def user_continue():
    global user_cont
    prompt_user = input("Do you wish to continue? Enter y/n: ")
    if prompt_user == "y":
        user_cont = True
    elif prompt_user == "n":
        user_cont = False
    return user_cont

# ------- Start Execution -------
get_productNum2()
```

Comment: How did you save your dictionary, ie. what is the format of the saved file? Did you pickle it? JSON?

Comment: @Kos The user entered the file name (see below). For this test, I made it "test.dat". I then duplicated it into a .txt file and copy and pasted those contents as my d= {} to test the rest of the program. I saw pickle and json but felt it was above my current basics. edit: oh that's awful formatting in a comment...
```    FILENAME = input(str("Please enter a file name: "))
    file = open(FILENAME, "w")
    file.write( str(products) )
    file.close()
    print("File saved.")```

Comment: Please explain the words "felt it was my current basics."  It seems like you don't want to use the standard modules that are provided to solve the exact problem you are asking about.

Comment: Don't just write the string representation of a dict to a file, that isn't how you do serialization. Look into `json` or `pickle`

Comment: @PaulCornelius I was editing my comment. It now says "felt it was above my current basics." It does seem like JSON and/or pickle is the correct option for this. I haven't gone into using these modules yet and only know making files.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is for serialization! lol Thank you pointing me in the right direction with JSON/pickle.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) write a dictionary to file in JSON format. Not only is it saved in a human-readable way, the JSON format also means the dictionary can even be loaded into many other programming languages and programs if needed!

Here is an example using the standard library package `json`:

```
import json

dict = {'ABCD': '0123', 'HJKL': '0987'}

dict_json = json.dumps(dict) #this line turns the dictionary into a JSON string
with open("my_dictionary.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(dict_json)
```

Given a dictionary in JSON format, we can load it like this:

```
with open("my_dictionary.json", "r") as infile: 
    dict = json.load(infile)
```

Now you can access `dict` which you loaded from file as if it were the original dictionary:

```
>>> print(dict["ABCD"])
0123
```